# Android widget for Google Tasks

Tags: gratis, android, todo, widget

On my laptop, I use [Google Tasks](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308887) to keep track of things I have to do/buy/read/etc.

I would like an Android widget to easily see my lists of tasks on my phone.

Requirements:

- Open source (free is also acceptable if it is lightweight, does not require registration other than Google, does not spy on me, shows no ads)
- Android widget

Ideally:

- Can display several widgets for several TODO lists
- Easy mark a task as done using the widget
- Easy add a task by tapping somewhere on the widget

Comment: A Google Service not spying on you somehow is a contradiction in terms :D I don't use any such, but while you're waiting for good recommendations, here's my list of Android Todo Apps that [Sync with GoogleTasks](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_23). The ones having a yellow star come without trackers (should be your preference), those with "monitor icons" come with invasive trackers (so you want to skip them).

Comment: @Izzy: Very convenient thanks! Did you develop tools to disassemble APKs and look for monitoring libraries/classes? :-)

Comment: Not really. I use APIs of services that do: Appbrain, Exodus Privacy. And for the apps in my repo, LibRadar plus my own scanner working on its side-products. All static scans, so it only tells whether those libraries are present, not if they are used (well, of course if they are not present they are not used, and that's when the star is applied).

Answer (score 1):

[Business Tasks](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.biztasks) is not open source, but it:

- Is free
- Runs on Android 4.1 and above
- Has a widget
- Contains no tracker according to [IzzyOnDroid](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_todo#group_23)
- Several widgets can display several TODO lists
- Ability to remove and add tasks

Screenshot:

[image]